# Why does Vue router regex trigger on all paths?

Tags: javascript, regex, vuejs2

I am using VueJS2, and having some trouble with the router.

My routes are set up as follows:

```
import TypeoneSignup from "../components/typeone-signup";
import TypetwoSignup from "../components/typetwo-signup";
import SomeSecretPath from "../components/some-secret-path";
import RegisterSecretRecord from "../components/register-secret-record";
import RegisteredSuccess from "../components/registered-success";
import ErrorView from "../components/error-view";
import FourOhFour from "../components/four-oh-four";
import TargetPage from "../components/targetpage-redirect";

export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Ttypeone-signup',
        path: '/signup-typeone',
        component: TypeoneSignup
    },
    {
        name: 'typetwo-signup',
        path: '/signup-typetwo',
        component: TypetwoSignup
    },
    {
        name: 'some-secret-path',    
        path: '/some-secret-path/:token',
        component: SomeSecretPath,
        props: (route) => ({ token: route.params.token })
    },
   {
       name: 'registered-success',
       path: '/success',
       component: RegisteredSuccess
   },
   {
       name: 'error',
       path: '/error',
       component: ErrorView
   },
   {
       name: 'register-secret-record',
       path: '/register-secret-record/:token',
       component: RegistersecretRecord,
       props: (route) => ({ token: route.params.token })
   },
   {
       name: '404',
       path: '/404',
       component: FourOhFour
   },
   {
       name: 'targetpage',
       path: '(/?)$',
       component: TargetPage
   },
    {
     path: '*',
     redirect: '404'
   }
];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever a user enters mydomain.com or mydomain.com/, they should be redirected to myotherdomain.com. That's what the targetpage-redirect does.

The user should however not be redirected if he enters mydomain.com/anypath, since there are specific paths that they need to access at certain times. Effectively im trying to set up a "front page" style redirect.

The issue however is, that the TargetPage seems to "trigger" on any and all urls/paths that are used.

I've tried verifying it with the [Express route tester](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/), and it says that it should correctly only trigger on paths that contain one or no slashes, and then ends.

So what causes the redirect from all other paths?

**Edit:**
So, having looked around and haphazardly commenting out pieces of code, it seems that there is not an issue with the regex itself, but rather the

```
import TargetPage from "../components/targetpage-redirect";
```

part that somehow forces the script in the page to be run.
My targetpage-redirect looks as follows:

```
<template>

</template>
<script>
    window.location.replace("https://myotherdomain.com");

</script>
```

Can it really be true that a page like that cannot be imported without executing the script, or am I completely misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a dummy component for this, you should simply use `beforeEnter` :

```
{
    path: '(/?)$',
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        window.location = 'https://myotherdomain.com'
    }
}
```

Read more : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I did not know that this was called navigation guards. Thank you very much. Also seemed the regex wasn't needed/didn't work in practice, and could be replaced with just a single /